# apex:selectList inside a table column does not display correctly

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

I've added an apex:selectList inside of a table column in a visualforce page.  The rendered output is wrong - the selectList doesn't show up in the correct column - it actually gets rendered in a new row along with some other misc table row / column tags:

Visualforce page markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Lead Source</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>
                <apex:selectList value="{!item1LeadSource}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!leadSources}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Rendered output

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Donation Source</th>
            <th>Lead Source</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="data2Col " colspan="2">
                <select name="j_id0:j_id28:j_id33:j_id34:j_id39" size="1">  
                    <option value="Web" selected="selected">Web</option>
                    <option value="Phone Inquiry">Phone Inquiry</option>
                    <option value="Partner Referral">Partner Referral</option>
                    <option value="Purchased List">Purchased List</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="data2Col " colspan="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is this normal?

Comment: Remember that these apex:... tags are designed to work together to produce heavily styled HTML/CSS output from some quite simple markup. I suggest you stick to all apex:... tags or all raw HTML (just using things like apex:repeat) rather than mixing the two. Using all apex:... keeps your pages styled consistently with the platform; using raw HTMl allows you to do your own thing.

Comment: Yes, this would be "normal". I recommend the following resources [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).

Comment: @KeithC I tried building the options by using apex:repeat instead of selectList + selectOptions - the result was the options were wrapped in their own tags too (not a child of the select tags).

Comment: @crmprogdev The first link is broken, the second link is generic.

Comment: Thanks Dan. SF has been changing all their docs. Here's the correct link: [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/).

Comment: @DanBough See the code I posted as an answer for emitting your own HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment thread, going the raw HTML route, this page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <select>
        <apex:repeat value="{!options}" var="o">
            <option value="{!o.value}">{!o.label}</option>
        </apex:repeat>
    </select>
</apex:page>
```

and this controller:

```
public class TestController {
    public SelectOption[] options {
        get {
            return new SelectOption[] {
                    new SelectOption('abc', 'abc'),
                    new SelectOption('def', 'def')
                    };
        }
   }
}
```

will output this HTML:

```
<select>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="def">def</option>
</select>
```

(You don't have to use the `SelectOption` class especially if the values and labels are the same.)

Comment: Thanks!  This code produced a similar issue in that the options ended up outside of the select tags in the page I'm working on.  I set up another test page that only contained this code and it worked fine.  So I think the answer to my original question ("is this normal") is 'No' - there is something else going on in my page that is breaking things.